# jquery.cookie.js is loaded only for authenticated users, by jQuery update module

Tags: 7, javascript, cookies

jquery.cookie.js is loaded only for authenticated users and i cannot really figure out why.
The page caching is disabled.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `jQuery.cookie` library is not always included, it depends the user state and the visiting page.

For example, the login form includes this library by attaching (`#attached`) it to the form.

What you could do is include it yourself in a custom module or in your theme.

```
// hook_init()
function YOURMODULE_init() 
{
     drupal_add_library('system', 'jquery.cookie');
}

// or in theme preprocess
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_page(&$vars)
{
     drupal_add_library('system', 'jquery.cookie');
}
```

Comment: Well the script is loaded for authenticated users from jQuery update module, i could load it explicitly in a hook_init but that looks weird

Comment: Accepted the answer because drupal_add_library('system', 'jquery.cookie'); loads the script only once, even if you are authenticated, so thats OK

Comment: Yes, thats handy when using `drupal_add_library`, it will be only include the library once, even if you called it multiple times.